# Rendering pdf with pdf.js -- a promise returns unusable result

Tags: javascript, pdf, promise, pdf.js

I reasearched and experimented quite a bit with rendering pdfs in html using pdf.js, a demanding task for a noob like me.

I thought a combination of the below html and JS might have been a good start, but I am still stuck.

Html part:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>PDF.js Example</title>
  <script src="build/pdf.js"></script>
  <script src="simple-g-SO.js"></script>

  <style media="screen">
  .button {
    background-color: #333;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 25px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  li:hover {
    background-color: #111;
  }

  ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }

  li {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
  }

  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <ul>
    <li><button onclick="leftOnePage()" type="button" class="button" id="left"><</button></li>
    <li><button onclick="rightOnePage()" type="button" class="button" id="right">></button></li>
  </ul>
  <br/>
  <canvas id="pdf"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

plus this JS code:

```
async function renderPdf(pdfDocument,pdfPageN) {
  // Load information from page pdfPageN
  const page = await pdfDocument.getPage(pdfPageN);

  const scale = 1.5;
  const viewport = page.getViewport(scale);

  // Apply page dimensions to the <canvas> element.
  const canvas = document.getElementById("pdf");
  const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  canvas.height = viewport.height;
  canvas.width = viewport.width;

  // Render the page into the <canvas> element.
  const renderContext = {
    canvasContext: context,
    viewport: viewport
  };
  await page.render(renderContext);
};

async function loadPdf(){
  // load the pdf
  const loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument("http://static.kjuicer.com/varie/fuffa/test.pdf");
  const pdf = await loadingTask.promise;
  return pdf
}

async function initialRenderPdf(){
  const pdfDoc = await loadPdf()
  const renderingPdf = await renderPdf(pdfDoc,pageViewed)
  return pdfDoc
}

pageViewed = 1
myPdf = initialRenderPdf()

//called on left button click
function leftOnePage(){
    if(pageViewed<=1){
        return
    } else {
    pageViewed -= 1
        renderPdf(myPdf,pageViewed)
    }
}

//called on right button click
async function rightOnePage(){
    if(pageViewed>=10){
        return
    } else {
    pageViewed += 1
        await renderPdf(myPdf,pageViewed)
    }
}
async function renderPdf(pdfDocument,pdfPageN) {
  // Load information from page pdfPageN
  const page = await pdfDocument.getPage(pdfPageN);

  const scale = 1.5;
  const viewport = page.getViewport(scale);

  // Apply page dimensions to the <canvas> element.
  const canvas = document.getElementById("pdf");
  const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  canvas.height = viewport.height;
  canvas.width = viewport.width;

  // Render the page into the <canvas> element.
  const renderContext = {
    canvasContext: context,
    viewport: viewport
  };
  await page.render(renderContext);
};

async function loadPdf(){
  // load the pdf
  const loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument("http://static.kjuicer.com/varie/fuffa/test.pdf");
  const pdf = await loadingTask.promise;
  return pdf
}

async function initialRenderPdf(){
  const pdfDoc = await loadPdf()
  const renderingPdf = await renderPdf(pdfDoc,pageViewed)
  return pdfDoc
}

pageViewed = 1
myPdf = initialRenderPdf()

//called on left button click
function leftOnePage(){
    if(pageViewed<=1){
        return
    } else {
    pageViewed -= 1
        renderPdf(myPdf,pageViewed)
    }
}

//called on right button click
async function rightOnePage(){
    if(pageViewed>=10){
        return
    } else {
    pageViewed += 1
        await renderPdf(myPdf,pageViewed)
    }
}
```

(They run in the root directory of a pdf.js setup, which can be downloaded [here](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/getting_started/#download))

I can't figure out if I am overlooking some promise-related issue, or understanding the use of pdf.js wrong.

The first page of the pdf will display correctly. As soon as I try to switch to a different page invoking `rightOnePage()` with the right button, it throws a "TypeError: pdfDocument.getPage is not a function" at me. `pdfDocument.getPage` makes use of the result of `loadPdf()`.

Yet the `loadPdf()` function should return the pdf object correctly: it works when called from `initialRenderPdf()`.

I tried also setting `myPdf = initialRenderPdf()[1]`, which changed the error to `TypeError: pdfDocument is undefined`, but does not solve it. Neither does using a `myPdf.then(renderPdf(myPdf,pageViewed))` version of the command inside the `rightOnePage()` function.

I would benefit significantly from a bit of guidance...

PS: I might also need some kind of clearing the canvas before invoking the new render of a page. I faced that issue on a different attempt at reaching the goal, but did not get that far yet.

Comment: It might help to realise that the thing you cache, `myPdf`, is a promise, which needs to be awaited every time it is used.

Comment: It did! By making the call `renderPdf(await myPdf,pageViewed)` instead than `renderPdf(myPdf,pageViewed)`, it worked perfectly. Thank you @Roamer-1888! I wonder why it works as is in the first call, but my problem is now gone. :)

Comment: At first call, the promise is awaited at the point where it is cached, `const pdfDoc = await loadPdf();`, followed immediately, as you would expect, by a successful rendering. Your problem lay in the lack of awaits thereafter, on page changes.

Answer (score 1):

The issue should be in your:

```
async function loadPdf(){
  // load the pdf
  const loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument("http://static.kjuicer.com/varie/fuffa/test.pdf");
  const pdf = await loadingTask.promise;
  return pdf
}
```

The `getDocument` method already returns a promise. In order to get back the data from it, you can simply do:

```
const pdf = await pdfjsLib.getDocument("http://static.kjuicer.com/varie/fuffa/test.pdf");
```

Even shorter, your method could directly be something like:

```
async function loadPdf(){
  return await pdfjsLib.getDocument("http://static.kjuicer.com/varie/fuffa/test.pdf");
}
```

Comment: your code looks much prettier, but the result seems to be the same :/ i.e.: the first page loads properly, but the pdf object works fine only when called from inside initialRenderPdf(). When the object is returned from initialRenderPdf(), it then does not seem to perform properly.

Answer (score 0):

the getDocument() have a property promise that need await:

```js
const loadingPdfDocument = pdfjsLib.getDocument(typedArray);
const pdfDocumentInstance = await loadingPdfDocument.promise;
```